# Java Guice Named Bindings with Objects provided from other modules

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

Heres my current setup

**Class file**

```java
public class ToyAdapter {

private final ToyClient toyClient;
private final Retryer retryer;

    @Inject
    public APIAdapter(final ToyClient toyClient,
                        @Named("toyRetryer") final Retryer retryer) {
        this.toyClient = toyClient;
        this.retryer = retryer;
    }
```

**Guice file**
I have several guice modules, but this one pertains to the above class

```java
public class ToyModule extends AbstractModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {

        bind(ToyAdapter.class).in(Singleton.class);
        bind(Retryer.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("toyRetryer")).toInstance(getToyRetryer());
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public ToyClient getToyClient(...){
       ...
    }

    private Retryer getToyRetryer() {#Takes no arguments
        return RetryerBuilder...build();
    }
}
```

So far this works great! However, now my retryer requires a LogPublisher object provided in another module.

I'm trying

```java
public class ToyModule extends AbstractModule {

    LogPublisher logPublisher;

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        requestInjection(logPublisher);
        bind(ToyAdapter.class).in(Singleton.class);
        bind(Retryer.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("toyRetryer")).toInstance(getToyRetryer());
    }
    
    private Retryer getToyRetryer() {
        return RetryerBuilder.withLogPublisher(logPublisher).build();
    }
}
```

LogPublisher is provided in another guice module which has alot of other objects that depend on LogPublisher so I'd rather not just merge everything into one giant guice module.

```
@Provides
@Singleton
public LogPublisher getLogPublisher() {...}
```

Is this the proper way to do this? I'm getting Java findBugs errors saying `unwritten field` so I'm thinking I'm doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare your `Retryer` with help of `@Provides`/`@Named` annotations.

```java
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @Named("toyRetryer")
    public Retryer getToyRetryer(LogPublisher logPublisher) {
        return RetryerBuilder.withLogPublisher(logPublisher).build();
    }
```

Comment: thank you, can I use javax.inject.Named or do I have to use the guice one?

Comment: It should be ok with either of them, but I would stick with `javax.inject`

Comment: could you explain why this works?